# Excel - Returning a column heading when data is below

Tags: excel

I'm fairly inexperienced at this, but I am quickly learning.  I'm a teacher that was told to keep a list of different field trips students have attended throughout the year.  Can I generate a list of only the trips each student attended?

Individual student names down left, and columns contain the trip names.  I populated the cells with a "1" if they attended the trip.

[screen shot of my excel document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhz7J.png)

HELP!  : -)

Comment: Auto filter? Pivot table?

Comment: What excel are you using?

Comment: That's a lot of field trips...I sure wish my teachers put together that many!  In the end, you'd like perhaps a drop down where you can choose a student name, then when you choose a name, the column next to it fills with the field trips the student was on?

Comment: Tough to accomplish with just formulas in particular cause you can't concatenate natively strings in an array. You might need to use VBA unless the field trips are limited amount and you can hardcode the names into your formula using for example cascading IF's.

Comment: @nbayly that depends on which Excel the OP is using.  The most recent upgrade to Office 365 add a formula TEXTJOIN, which can be used as an Array formula. This will do exactly what the OP is asking.  Hence my question.

Comment: @ScottCraner was not familiar with that function. Thank you for the clarification. Regards

Comment: Unfortunately we are running M O 2010 still.  I do have access to Office 365 and can easily move things over to try.

Comment: @BruceWayne The field trips are for the gifted education program in the school.  As a grade level for regular ed., they are taking 2 or 3 a year.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple structure that you can adapt.  Column **A** contains the student names.  Row **#1** contain the field trips *(most are to the moons of Uranus, one to to Springfield)*:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub TripTracker()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, v As String
    For i = 2 To 6
        v = ""
        For j = 2 To 23
            If Cells(i, j) = 1 Then v = v & ", " & Cells(1, j)
        Next j
        Cells(i, 24).Value = Mid(v, 2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce a per student trip list in column **X**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I will be trying a few of these ideas tonight and will let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution with no VBA necessary.

Instead of populating the cell with "1" if they attend a trip, populate the cell with "," and the name of the trip.

You can use counta() to count the trips for each student and then concatenate each cell on the right side of the table.

This will give you a sum of the trips for each student and a handy list:

```
=Substitute(Concatenate(cell1, cell2...celln),",","",1)
```

This is a little cumbersome as you have to choose each cell to concatenate for the first row, but you can drag the formula down to work for all rows.  This makes it easy to add students to the list, just drag your formulas down.

Substituting the first comma with ZLS will remove the leading comma.

[image: Sample!]